# USB-C Ports blowing on Monitor with Lenovo Laptops

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, usb-c

We have a real headache in our office. We are currently using Lenovo laptops, they are coming near to EOL and are a mixture of T480/490s - L380/390s etc. We had some Philips monitors and around half of them the USB-C ports on them no longer work. They can only be used via HDMI. Now these Philips screens are around 5/6 years old, so we put this down to wear and tear. However we recently got some new Dell C2422HE monitors and the exact same thing is happening. Around half of them already have blown USB-C docks and no longer work unless using HDMI. I can only think of power surges or some odd incompatibility between the Lenovo laptops and the monitors. Any ideas on whats causing this or how we can narrow down the possible cause.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, buy high-speed braided cables:  [Amazon - USB-C Cables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BNXKSDNJ)

Make sure you use Display Port cables and turn on MST option on the Dell monitors to use them as built-in docking stations.

Also, under the Dell monitor menu- look for where it says " "High-Resolution Rate" and make sure you CHANGE it to  "High Data Speed"

Last but not least, update the firmware to the latest version.

Good luck!

-JR

Comment: This doesn't the question in any shape or form. Cables have nothing to do with it. The author mentioned it used to work.